# Cannot access database API in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on the following tutorial on Django (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/).

When I invoke the interactive shell to access the database API using the command 
python manage.py shell, I receive the following prompt 
In [1]:

Please can someone tell me what this means and how I can access the database API.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't paste the error. Can you do it?

Comment: do you happen to use ipython? `In [x]:` is what is output before every line in ipython, it is working properly. just follow [Playing with the API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) in the tutorial. Make sure you are importing your models first. `from polls.models import Poll, Choice`...

Comment: You need to add your error or we cannot help you

Comment: When I use the command python manage.py shell, I get the output: IPython 0.12.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: How can I escape this and proceed to normal >>> from polls.models import Poll, Choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the normal shell prompt, I don't think it's a bug, maybe you want to check the commands offered by manage.py because I think you wanted to do something else.